# How to bind DataGridView with List<T> or BindingList<T>

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I've done it one thousand of times and it works but now .... not :(

Am I doing something wrong here because nothing is shown in grid ?

```
namespace theGridIsNotWorking
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = new List<Item>();

        items.Add(new Item(){ TheName = "first"});
        items.Add(new Item(){ TheName = "Second"});
        items.Add(new Item(){ TheName = "Third"});

        dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<Item>(items);
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string TheName;
    }
}
}
```

Nothing spectaculos .... but really sad.

Comment: Have you set the `PropertyName` property of each DataColumn?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that TheName is a member variable, but you need a property.
Try the following for the Item class:

```
      public class Item
      {
         public string TheName;

         public string TheNameProperty
         {
            get
            {
               return TheName;
            }
         }

         public Item(string name)
         {
            TheName = name;
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [BindingListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/). Easiest way to bind a List<T> to a DGV.

Answer (score 1):

```
BindingList<Notification>(notifications);
```

shouldn't it be

```
BindingList<Notification>(activeNotifications);
```

?

Comment: sorry for mistake ... it's gramatically only ... this is a demo purpose ... with activeNotifications has to be, doesn't work :(

Comment: I thought it will be easy... I tried the code and it works fine. First, are you sure that this code is run? Second, did you set anything on DataGridView?

Comment: on my machne the grid is still empty ... I'm using vs2008, .net 3.5 ... :(